# Tensorflow Seq2Seq Translate Tutorial Placeholder Variables

Tags: tensorflow

I'm curious about the usage of placeholders in the seq2seq tutorial. I see that they're initializing the placeholders to be the size of the largest bucket in lines 141-147:

```
for i in xrange(buckets[-1][0]):  # Last bucket is the biggest one.
  self.encoder_inputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None],
                                            name="encoder{0}".format(i)))
for i in xrange(buckets[-1][1] + 1):
  self.decoder_inputs.append(tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None],
                                            name="decoder{0}".format(i)))
  self.target_weights.append(tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=[None],
                                            name="weight{0}".format(i)))
```

what I don't understand is why this works with buckets that are smaller than this size. In the step() call, when the encoder_inputs are being initialized, if, for example, the bucket size used 50 when the max bucket size is 100, won't the last 50 values in the placeholder remain uninitialized? Or is there a step that I'm missing that initializes all of the values, even the values that won't be used at calculation time?

Comment: Looks like there is some padding to solve this problem. According to https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html : 
"we prepend the special GO symbol to the input data. This is done in the get_batch() function in seq2seq_model.py ... To put it all together, imagine we have the sentence "I go.", tokenized as ["I", "go", "."] as input and the sentence "Je vais." as output, tokenized ["Je", "vais", "."]. It will be put in the (5, 10) bucket, with encoder inputs representing [PAD PAD "." "go" "I"] and decoder inputs [GO "Je" "vais" "." EOS PAD PAD PAD PAD PAD]."

Comment: Yes but I think that padding is used within each bucket. In the example above, that puts the sentence "I go" and "Je vais" into the (5,10) bucket. But in the initialization of the placeholder variables, the placeholders are initialized to hold up to the bucket of size (40, 50). I have been getting the following error : 
Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'gpu_scope_0/encoder50_gpu0' with dtype int32
when trying to do something similar (in my code I know that I don't give tensor gpu_scope_0/encoder50_gpu0 a value)